# Connect to Oracle ATP with Nifi

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi, ojdbc

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database on Oracle Cloud, which requires the use of an SSL wallet + TNS names.
I've set up Nifi in docker, and however I'm not able to connect to the database. I've tested connectivity to the database using the SSL wallet and I am able to from the host, but not from Nifi.

I've followed the instructured at https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html

And the settings for the DB connection pool in Nifi looks like this:

[Nifi DBCP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2LyW.png)

However I get the error that it isn't able to resolve the TNS name.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILonh.png)

Could someone advise on how to connect from Nifi to Oracle ATP (or any Oracle database using an SSL wallet?)

Comment: Please provide a full error stacktrace from log file. So we'll see the error from oracle driver. Also share your connection url. Please everything as a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL looks fine. Be sure to use the latest JDBC driver from Oracle.
Here is the download page:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Also you must have the following companion jars along with ojdbc8.jar. These jars are: oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar, osdt_cert.jar.

Also note that when connecting to ADB-S you might want to explicitly disable FAN in the driver otherwise you'll see a 10ms delay when creating the very first new connection. You can do that by setting "oracle.jdbc.fanEnabled" to "false" in ojdbc.properties (which is part of wallet.zip).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I have those downloaded already. Do they need to be referenced at all or just the ojdbc file? 
And thanks for the properties suggestion, hopefully that will make a difference when I get it working.

Does the error message of 'Could not resolve the connect identifer of x_high' suggest that the JDBC files and TNS files are being loaded, or that its a genuine connectivity issue with the database?

Comment: The error suggests that your tnsnames.ora file wasn't found. Be sure that in your url the path specified in TNS_ADMIN is correct.

Answer (score 1):

you are using DBALIAS forme jdbc:oracle:thin:@dblias

so you need a tnsname.ora file into (TNS_ADMIN directory)

tnsname.ora file is formated:
DBALIAS = (connect string)

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sample_tnsnames.ora.htm

you can use directly the forme with the description:

"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=prodHost))) (connect_data=(INSTANCE_NAME=ORCL)))";

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
This doesn't take into account the use of a wallet. For use with a wallet, you have to use a tnsnames.ora file in the same folder as the certificates+keystore. So I can't use the long form tns connect.

Comment: what version of jdbc do you use ? and did /opt/jdbc/wallet/tnsnames.ora readable